# Python dictionary vs. database

Tags: python, database, dictionary, installation, key-value-store

In my brief experience, the Python `dict` data structure slows down the program execution as the number of keys reach few tens of thousands. I need a fast key-value store to handle up to a million pairs, where keys could be `int` or `str` and values are `str`. I need an alternative which I can install as a non-root user on the Unix server.

Which one of the alternatives would you recommend?

1. leveldb (or any other DB) + Plyvel API, or
2. a PyPi leveldb library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/leveldb

Are these equivalent alternatives in terms of functionality, performance, and code-maintenance (I am assuming Google's leveldb repo is ahead in terms of updates and bug-fixes)?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Redis (http://redis.io/) it can and should be run as non-root and can be compiled and started in your home directory (or whatever dir you can write to without root privs). It's also written in C, but used by a lot of other projects. It has APIs for all programming languages that count and an active community.
I've never heard of leveldb before and it's not quite actively developed looking at githubs commit log.

HTH & have a nice day!

Basti